# android jni from static to non static methods

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am trying to refactor some android jni code. It was initially setup to use static variables in JNI and static calls on the android side. I would like to change that to improve compatibility with other code.

current method signatures

```
static jclass main_activity;

static jmethodID on_init;
static jmethodID on_update;
static jmethodID on_render;
static jmethodID on_exit;
static jmethodID on_get_input;
```

these bindings were setup in the beginning of the code like this:

```
main_activity = (jclass)((*mEnv)->NewGlobalRef(mEnv, cls));

on_init = (*mEnv)->GetStaticMethodID(mEnv, main_activity,
                            "on_native_init","()V");
on_update = (*mEnv)->GetStaticMethodID(mEnv, main_activity,
                            "on_native_update","()V");
on_render = (*mEnv)->GetStaticMethodID(mEnv, main_activity,
                            "on_native_render","()V");
on_exit = (*mEnv)->GetStaticMethodID(mEnv, main_activity,
                            "on_native_exit", "()V");
```

Then later in the code they would be used like this:

```
void Android_JNI_SwapEGLwindow(void)
{
    JNIEnv *a_env = get_android_jni_env();
    (*mEnv)->CallStaticVoidMethod(a_env, main_activity, on_update);
}
```

Since this project is currently setup to store the main activity and the function addresses as a static reference with only the call to `get_android_jni_env();` allowing me access to get the current android jni environment.

How can I restructure this code to be able to get an instance instead of holding on to a static reference?

Comment: Even if you make these methods in MainActivity class non-static, you will still need to keep a global reference to your MainActivity instance. Worse, today you can keep this reference in Java, but now you will need to know it in your native code, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one static method as "getInstance()" to retreive the object of class main_activity, then you can use the object to call non-static methods.

```
jmethodID midGetInstance = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, main_activity_class, "getInstance", "()Lcom/package/yourapp/MainActivity;");
jobject main_activity_obj = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, main_activity_class, midGetInstance);
...NewGlobalRef(main_activity_obj);
```

where `main_activity_class` is the same of your original jclass main_activity.

On Java side, you need

```
onCreate(...) {mInstance = this;...}
public static MainActivity getInstance() {return mInstance;}
```

Then you can use `main_acitivty_obj` to access the non-static methods.